# Navigation in in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a request from a client who wants to skip one page in opening under some conditions and immediately open another page. However the problem is that when it goes back it wants to always show 2 pages. So page 1 opens page 3 and when I go back from page 3 it goes to page 2 and then station 1. I'm new to flutter and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you include that you;ve tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Use pushReplacement for such Navigation

```
// In Screen 1
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, Screen3()) // Or Screen2()

// In Screen 3
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, Screen2())

// In Screen 2
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, Screen1())
```

Answer (score 0):

From page 1 to page 3 your can use

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page3()),
```

Then if you want to go to Page 2 from page 3 use  WillPopScope in page 3

```dart
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: (){},
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Add the above code in page 3. Add condition to check if it should go to Page 1 or 2 in `onWillPop` and again use navigator.pop or navigator.pushReplacement